# Group of elements in Raphaël

Tags: raphael

Is there a way to group elements in Raphaël on something like a layer in illustrator? So I can rotate translate delete the whole group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe what you are after is Paper.set()

**See:** http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Paper.set

It allows you to group several elements together so you can manipulate them all at once.

Answer (score 8):

In case you need to have a real  element, here is a small plugin. It's kind of old but a beginning:

https://github.com/meszaros-lajos-gyorgy/Raphael-Plugins/blob/master/dev/raphael.group.js

And here is another website which created a small plugin:

http://2hats.net/_box/raphael/grouping.html

The reason why an extra plugin is needed is because Raphaels set() function does not create a real DOM element!

> Creates array-like object to keep and operate several elements at once. Warning: it doesn’t create any elements for itself in the page, it just groups existing elements. Sets act as pseudo elements — all methods available to an element can be used on a set.

Comment: Hi Flek, your answer looks promising. I had to do an animation and started with Raphael as SVG-Jquery documentation looked unfriendly to me and Raphael is so well documented and popular. Iv asked a ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741579/raphael-boundry-issues-with-scaling and now I feel without grouping its not possible. Can raphael.group.js be used to solve it?

Comment: Please notice that the first link is dead and the second link is an ugly hack. RaphaelJS is open source. Direct implementation would be preferred. If there just would be someone who would have the time! :-/